# Mongodb field search priority for keyword search option

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

We have around 7 million records in Mongo Atlas. There are multiple text fields in each record. We want to give first priority to `AssetName` and so on, so we have given priority as below.

```
filters.append({
            'text': {
                'path': ['AssetName','JobTitle', 'CompanyName','Industry','CampaignName'],
                'query': args['keyword']
            }
        })
```

Issues, there are many records where "Assetname" field is not present.

So we are getting results where results are based on `CompanyName` or `JobTitle` but not the `Assetname`.

Out of 7 million, we would have `Assetname` in 2 million records. The rest of the records do not have `Assetname`.

How should I write the query so that it gives result matching`Assetname` first?